# Does Electrum require the Satoshi client?

Tags: client, electrum

Bitcoin Armory is a client that sits on top of the official bitcoin client. Bitcoinj is a totally different client, separate from the official bitcoin client. Does Electrum also need the official bitcoin client, or is it separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Electrum doesn't require Bitcoin-Qt to be installed on your computer. Electrum and BitcoinJ aren't *full* clients, though, so they do rely on Bitcoin-Qt at some level -- Electrum through the Stratum network and BitcoinJ through the Bitcoin network's SPV mode.

Comment: It might be also good to add that Electrum doesn't require a local copy of the blockchain.

Comment: @theymos Electrum uses Electrum Servers that store the blockchain and broadcast signed transactions

Comment: @rdymac Yeah, and those servers run Bitcoin-Qt.

Comment: Sorry, I was answering to @7anner